# Automate git push and fetch with ansible, it's possible?

Tags: git, automation, ansible

I’m trying to automate deploys. I have two repositories. First I am cloning the repository (called DEV) to my PC, then push from my PC to the repository called QA.

Here my first yaml, this way I am cloning the external repository (DEV) on my local PC

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
 gather_facts: false
 tasks:
 - name: clone repo test
   git:
     repo: https://github.com/test/test-repo.git
     dest: /home/user/git-test/
     clone: yes
     update: yes
```

How do I push the repository located in */home/user/git-test* (local) to QA repository using Ansible?

Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if a repository has a checkout you don't push to it. The checkout and the current commit can get out of sync. Consider, what if QA is running a test and you push a new change to the QA checkout?

Instead, push to a branch in a central repository. Then QA periodically pulls from that branch. If there's a new commit, QA runs. Here is [an example of how to setup Ansible with Jenkins CI](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/integrating-ansible-jenkins-cicd-process). Note that the process starts with *pull* from repo.

[image]

Rather than setting up your own QA, [Ansible has existing integrations to Continuous Integration services](https://www.ansible.com/integrations/devops-tools). Some, like [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/), have free plans for small projects.